# R Studio executes code but does not produce expected graphs

Tags: r, plot

I have recently been having issues with R Studio executing code. The code executes, but does not generate graphs. I tested the code in RKWard, and it does the same thing. Is the error in my code (below) or something else?

```
library(popbio)
library(ggplot2)
library(DirichletReg)
library(tidyr)
library(gridExtra)


# Function to simulate allele frequencies over time with genetic drift, mutation, recombination, and extinction possibility
simulate_population <- function(pop_size, num_generations, num_alleles_per_ploidy, selection_coefficients, fitness_costs, ploidies, extinction_threshold, drift_coefficient, mutation_rate, environmental_effect, recombination_rate) {
  # Storage for allele frequencies and alleles over time
  allele_freqs_list <- list()
  alleles_list <- list()

  for (i in seq_along(ploidies)) {
    ploidy <- ploidies[i]
    num_alleles <- num_alleles_per_ploidy[i]

    # Initial allele frequencies and alleles
    initial_freqs <- rep(1/num_alleles, num_alleles)
    alleles <- matrix(1:num_alleles, nrow = 1, ncol = num_alleles)

    # Storage for allele frequencies and alleles over time
    allele_freqs <- matrix(NA, nrow = num_generations, ncol = num_alleles)
    allele_freqs[1,] <- initial_freqs

    alleles_over_time <- list()
    alleles_over_time[[1]] <- alleles

    # Simulation loop
    for (gen in 2:num_generations) {
      # Check for extinction
if (sum(!is.na(allele_freqs[gen - 1, ])) == 0) {
  allele_freqs[gen,] <- rep(0, num_alleles)
  alleles_over_time[[gen]] <- matrix(0, nrow = 1, ncol = 1)
  break  # Stop simulation if extinct
}



      # Selection with environmental effect
      fitness <- 1 - (selection_coefficients + environmental_effect) * fitness_costs
      fitness_scaled <- fitness / sum(fitness)

      # Frequencies after selection
      freqs_after_selection <- allele_freqs[gen-1,] * fitness_scaled

      # Genetic drift
      freqs_after_drift <- rbinom(num_alleles, size = pop_size, prob = freqs_after_selection) / pop_size
      freqs_after_drift <- freqs_after_drift + drift_coefficient * (initial_freqs - freqs_after_drift)

      # Recombination
      recombination_freqs <- rbinom(num_alleles, size = pop_size, prob = recombination_rate) / pop_size
      freqs_after_recombination <- recombination_step(freqs_after_drift, recombination_freqs)

      # Mutation
mutation_freqs <- rbinom(num_alleles, size = pop_size, prob = mutation_rate) / pop_size
new_alleles <- which(mutation_freqs > 0)

if (length(new_alleles) > 0) {
  # Add new alleles
  num_new_alleles <- length(new_alleles)
  alleles <- cbind(alleles, matrix((num_alleles + 1):(num_alleles + num_new_alleles), nrow = 1, ncol = num_new_alleles))

  # Update allele frequencies considering ploidy
  freqs_after_ploidy <- rdirichlet(1, alpha = pop_size * mutation_freqs / ploidy + 0.001) # Add a small constant

  # Check if new alleles are introduced
  if (length(freqs_after_ploidy) > ncol(allele_freqs)) {
    # If yes, expand the matrix to accommodate new alleles
    allele_freqs <- cbind(allele_freqs, matrix(NA, nrow = num_generations, ncol = length(freqs_after_ploidy) - ncol(allele_freqs)))
  }

  # Update allele frequencies and alleles
  allele_freqs[gen, seq_along(freqs_after_ploidy)] <- freqs_after_ploidy

  # Extract the relevant columns from alleles matrix based on allele frequencies
  selected_alleles <- alleles[, seq_along(freqs_after_ploidy)]

  alleles_over_time[[gen]] <- selected_alleles
}


    # Save allele frequencies and alleles for this ploidy
    allele_freqs_list[[paste("Ploidy", ploidy, "_Alleles", num_alleles)]] <- allele_freqs
    alleles_list[[paste("Ploidy", ploidy, "_Alleles", num_alleles)]] <- do.call(cbind, alleles_over_time)
  }

  return(list(allele_freqs = allele_freqs_list, alleles = alleles_list))
}
# Plotting function to visualize allele frequencies and alleles over time
plot_allele_dynamics <- function(allele_freqs_list, alleles_list, ploidy, num_alleles) {
  # Define custom colors for each allele
  allele_colors <- c("blue", "red", "green", "purple", "orange", "pink", "brown", "cyan", "gray", "yellow", "darkgreen", "darkblue")

  # Create a data frame with proper column names for allele frequencies
  df_freqs <- as.data.frame(allele_freqs_list)
  colnames(df_freqs) <- paste0("Allele", 1:num_alleles)
  df_freqs$Generation <- seq_len(nrow(df_freqs))

  # Reshape data to long format for allele frequencies
  df_freqs_long <- tidyr::gather(df_freqs, key = "Allele", value = "Frequency", -Generation)

  # Create a data frame with proper column names for alleles
  df_alleles <- as.data.frame(alleles_list)
  colnames(df_alleles) <- paste0("Allele", 1:num_alleles)
  df_alleles$Generation <- seq_len(nrow(df_alleles))

  # Reshape data to long format for alleles
  df_alleles_long <- tidyr::gather(df_alleles, key = "Allele", value = "AlleleID", -Generation)

  # Merge data frames based on Generation and Allele
  df_merged <- merge(df_freqs_long, df_alleles_long, by.x = c("Generation", "Allele"), by.y = c("Generation", "Allele"))

  # Plot allele frequencies with custom colors
  p <- ggplot(data = df_merged, aes(x = Generation, y = Frequency, color = as.factor(Allele), group = AlleleID)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(title = paste("Simulation of Allele Frequencies (Ploidy", ploidy, ", Alleles", num_alleles, ")"),
         x = "Generations",
         y = "Allele Frequency") +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_color_manual(values = allele_colors[1:num_alleles])

  return(p)
}

# Set simulation parameters
pop_size <- 1000
num_generations <- 100
num_alleles_per_ploidy <- c(4, 6, 8)  # Set different numbers of alleles for each ploidy
selection_coefficients <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4)
fitness_costs <- c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04)
ploidies <- c(2, 3, 4)  # Set multiple ploidies
extinction_threshold <- 10  # Set the extinction threshold
drift_coefficient <- 0.01  # Set the genetic drift coefficient
mutation_rate <- 0.005  # Set the mutation rate
environmental_effect <- 0.1  # Set the environmental effect
recombination_rate <- 0.01  # Set the recombination rate

# Run simulation with different numbers of alleles for each ploidy
result <- simulate_population(pop_size, num_generations, num_alleles_per_ploidy, selection_coefficients, fitness_costs, ploidies, extinction_threshold, drift_coefficient, mutation_rate, environmental_effect, recombination_rate)

# Plot results for each ploidy
for (i in seq_along(ploidies)) {
  ploidy <- ploidies[i]
  num_alleles <- num_alleles_per_ploidy[i]

  # Call the plotting function
  plot <- plot_allele_dynamics(result$allele_freqs[[paste("Ploidy", ploidy, "_Alleles", num_alleles)]],
                                result$alleles[[paste("Ploidy", ploidy, "_Alleles", num_alleles)]],
                                ploidy, num_alleles)

  # Print the plot
  print(plot)
}
```

I've tried rebooting R studio, rebooting my machine, reinstalling R Studio, and clearing the cache. None seem to help.

Comment: Instead of a bunch of code, test a simple plot. Does `plot(1)` work? Does `ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()` work? If not, please share your `sessionInfo()`, and remove the complicated code from the question. If those basic plots **do** work and it is only the complex code that fails, try to make your code **minimal** to reproduce the problem--that will narrow down where the problem could be.

Comment: PloidyPhD, please consider how you can reduce this question to something quickly reproducible. If this is just a plotting thing, just plot something, please don't ask us to go through 119 lines of code to try to reproduce something that may be unique to your computer. If it requires a specific structure or class of object, then please use `dput(head(x)). At a minimum, consider provide a much smaller code block to give us just enough to dig into the _plotting_ issue.

Comment: It would likely reduce the problem-set significantly if you can reduce this down to "any plot", "just ggplot/grid", or "just `plot.DirichletReg`" (some specific plotting function). Further, since you said you tried this in RKWard, it seems highly unlikely that this is related to the [tag:rstudio] IDE, so I'm removing that red-herring/distraction.

Comment: I am unable to plot anything at this point. I tried other code that I know had worked previously.  It does not throw any specific error code.  I apologize for the large code block, I'm still trying to learn how to code correctly and I was unsure where the error might be so I didn't think it hurt to put in the whole thing. I can trim it significantly if that will make it better for people?

Comment: I'll also point out that this is not unique to my machine. I've tried this same code with the same result on my backup machine.